# Foursquare Api return just 1 result on `venue/photos` endpoint with userless authentication

Tags: node.js, api, foursquare

The result I get from `venue/photos` has different with the **User Authentication**.

In the first one I just receive one result (one photo) in the result but in the the second one it return normal result that I expected.

```
--userless authentication--
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/43695300f964a5208c291fe3/photos?client_id=****&client_secret=****&v=20181002
"photos": {
        "count": 1,
        "items": [
            {}
        ],
        "dupesRemoved": 0
    }

--user authentication--
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/43695300f964a5208c291fe3/photos?oauth_token=****&v=20181002
"photos": {
        "count": 30,
        "items": [
            {}
        ],
        "dupesRemoved": 0
    }
```

I didn't found any reasonable answer in [Foursquare Photo Doc](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/api/venues/photos) why the result has problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beginning on May 31st, foursquare made five changes in order to simplify their API and maintain the quality of their service as their developer community grows.

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/announcements#start-up-tier-launch

> The quantity of photos and tips per venue will be changed to 1 for Sandbox Tier and 2 Personal Tier

I think this change apply to userless authentication.

Comment: Is these changes for every users or just Developer accounts?

Comment: for every users except Official foursquare app